# How do I get out of file comparison and back to the upgrade

Tags: 14.04, server, do-release-upgrade

I'm currently upgrading my system over `SSH`

And it asked me to upgrade to a new version of `ports.conf`, I choose the option to compare the two differences..

How do I get back out of this without cancelling the upgrade?

Comment: You are probably viewing the output of `diff file1 file2 | more`. Press q to exit.

Comment: Amazing - so simple. Thank you @Jos, if you want to add it as an answer i'll accept.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried Q, q, ctrl-Q, ctrl-q. It responds to the up and down arrows, and shows an <ok> as if it's a button, but nothing lets me exits that screen.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are viewing the output of `diff old-conf-file new-conf-file | more`.

Simply press <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit.

Comment: Upper case is a solution.

Comment: Not for me. Neither upper nor lower case Q do anything at all.

Comment: @JohnSmith I had the same problem, that no key made me quit that comparison mode. I tried it multiple times, also with "Command" + "Shift" + "Q", but nothing happened. Finally, I tried simply a (lowercase) "q" again and it worked. I could not tell you more about it unfortunately but it seems that one can solve it just by trying the same combination multiple times (perhaps after having triggered something else unconsciously by so doing).

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Esc' key worked upgrading an old 14.04 system